# Unable to set the initial states of selected items in CheckComboBox

Tags: wpf, xceed, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am trying to use **Xceed CheckComboBox** and it works well except for a small issue. When the CheckComboBox is initially loaded, the selected items List is shown properly in the ToggleButton part of the CheckComboBox, but the checkboxes representating these items aren't checked. Here is the code that I am using

**XAML**

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="_combo"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RoomFacilities}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 DisplayMemberPath="FacilityName" 
                 SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedFaclities}" 
                    />
```

**View Model**

```
public class RoomBandUpdateViewModel : Screen, IHandle<RecordChanged<RoomFacility>>,
                                               IHandle<RecordDeleted<RoomFacility>> {
    private ObservableCollection<RoomFacility> _roomFacilities;
    public ObservableCollection<RoomFacility> RoomFacilities {
        get { return _roomFacilities; }
        set { _roomFacilities = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomFacilities); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<RoomFacility> _selectedFacilities;
    public ObservableCollection<RoomFacility> SelectedFaclities {
        get { return _selectedFacilities; }
        set { _selectedFacilities = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedFaclities); }
    }

    protected override void OnActivate() {
        SelectedFaclities = new ObservableCollection<RoomFacility>(RoomBand.Facilities);
        RoomFacilities = new ObservableCollection<RoomFacility>(facilityService.GetAll());
    }
}
```

I would like to know why, when **SelectedFacilities** are set properly in view model, the CheckComboBox's checkboxes are not checked according to the items in the **SelectedFacilities**. The interesting part is that the Toggle Button part of the CheckComboBox properly displays **SelectedFacilities** in comma separated list.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you fill `SelectedFacilities` and `RoomFacilities`. Make sure you have handled reference equality of `RoomFacility` correctly. In other words, the only way i could only reproduce the problem is when I fill the `ObservableCollection`s in the following pattern:

```
RoomFacilities m1 = new RoomFacilities() { FacilityName = "F1" };
RoomFacilities m2 = new RoomFacilities() { FacilityName = "F2" };
RoomFacilities m3 = new RoomFacilities() { FacilityName = "F3" };
RoomFacilities m4 = new RoomFacilities() { FacilityName = "F1"};
RoomFacilities m5 = new RoomFacilities() { FacilityName = "F2"};
RoomFacilities = new ObservableCollection<RoomFacilities>(new Collection<RoomFacilities>() { m1, m2, m3 });
        SelectedFacilities = new ObservableCollection<RoomFacilities>(new Collection<RoomFacilities>() { m4, m5 });
```

Note that although `m4` and `m5` have similar `FacilityName` (which is displayed in the `ToggleButton` of `CheckComboBox`, they will not be selected in the drop down panel, Unless you override the `Equals` method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is RoomFacilities)
    {
        RoomFacilities mod = (RoomFacilities)obj;
        if (mod.FacilityName == this.FacilityName)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return base.Equals(obj);
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return FacilityName.GetHashCode();
}
```

**In other words, `CheckComboBox` does not throw an exception if `SelectedItemsOverride` is NOT a subset of `ItemsSource`**

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate to collection into the constructor of your class, the property is not yet bound tu your component, so the PropertyChanged event of your ViewModel is not triggered by your component.

The observable collection Add() method didn't fire the PropertyChanged event but fire the CollectionChanged event.

Hope this help you